# Phonegap AutoHideSplashScreen not working properly on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I want to add 5 seconds of delay to the splash screen in my Phonegap (v. 3.5.0) application which I'm currently developing only for IOS.

- I've installed the cordova splash screen plugin:
  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/doc/index.md
- Added this line to my config.xml:

```html
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

- Added a timeout inside my "deviceready" function that should hide the splash screen after 5 seconds:

```html
setTimeout(function(){
  navigator.splashscreen.hide();
},5000);
```

When I test my app, the splash screen disappears immediately after 1 or 2 seconds ignoring the parameter I've added in the config.xml but if I try to tap on the content of my homepage for the next 5 seconds nothing happens. Like if there was something on top of it that prevents any type of interaction (the splash screen isn't visible). After 5 seconds I can tap the content of my section and start interacting with it.

I did a test removing the timeout with the code that should hide the splash screen and the result was the same but I couldn't tap on anything in the main section after 5 seconds. The normal behaviour in this case should be that the splash screen should be visible all the time.

Does anyone have any idea of which could be the cause of this strange behaviour?